# Setting up linux services on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to restart php-fpm and apache on my Amazon Linux 1 instances deployed via elastic beanstalk. I'm using a load balanced environment and want to automate the entire deploy process.

Does anybody have any additional information on [this post from aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-services)?

I'm simple trying to use a yaml file too restart these services (gracefully) after each deploy.

example:

```
services: 
  sysvinit:
    myservice:
      enabled: true
      ensureRunning: true
      commands: 
        - "command name used as trigger"
```

I'm really not sure what is acceptable input for the "myservices" section. Any help is appricated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't verified the following, but my understanding is as follows. Since you have to restart `php-fpm` and `apache` services your service section could be:

```
services: 
  sysvinit:
    php-fpm:
      enabled: true
      ensureRunning: true
      commands: 
        - 01_some_command_name
    apache:
      enabled: true
      ensureRunning: true
      commands: 
        - 02_some_other_command_name
```

The `01_some_command_name` and `02_some_other_command_name` are names of commands in [commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) section. For example:

```
commands:
  01_some_command_name: 
    command: echo "execute command 01"
  02_some_other_command_name: 
    command: echo "execute command 02"
```

Execution of the two commands, should trigger in my view the restart of the `php-fpm` and `apache` services.

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try and report back if it works. One other curiosity, on elastic beanstalk the container_sommands run before the (default) composer install command. Is it possible to restart these services after the composer install?